# How far can you pee on the moon vs. mars?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, projectile, planets, estimation

Let's suppose you are at Elon Musk's Future Mars colony and you drank too much beer, how far can you pee on Mars if you can pee one meter on earth?

If the next day you get on the shuttle to the moon colony and when you arrive, you again drink too much beer, how far can you pee on the moon?

What is the ratio of Mar pee distance to Moon pee distance?

Assume the height of the Toilet bowl is 14 inches and the height of the man's Genitalia is 3 feet.

Comment: Distance varies inversely proportional to the square root of acceleration of gravity. You could use Newton's Laws to derive the relation.

Comment: It is hard to tell because the urine will boil off readily on Moon

Comment: the peeing takes place inside of a colony structure with life support system...

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like homework, so I'll guide you to finding the relevant variables neglecting any drag or friction.

Well, suppose your pee comes out horizontally with velocity $v$, parallel to the planet surface, and it comes out a height $h$ from the ground. If the planet has gravity $g$, the urine coming out will hit the ground after a time

$$t=\sqrt\frac{2h}{g}.$$

As such, since gravity does not act on horizontal components of the motion, the distance your pee hits the ground is given by

$$d=vt.$$

Since $v$ and $h$ can be considered characteristic of your body, you can find an equation that gives you a dependence on distance $d$ and surface gravity. Substituting that $d=1\mathrm m$ when $g=9.81\mathrm{m/s^2}$ should enable you to find the distances for other planets given their gravity.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you are peeing with a velocity v at angle θ with the horizontal. Then the range would be given by :

R = v²sin2θ/g

The ratio of the ranges in different gravitational fields would be

R_1 : R_2= g_2 : g_1

On the same ratio on moon Vs Mars would come out to be

0.44